# "A cat named Easter"

Tags: meaning-in-context, lyrics, poetry, names

There is a song called ["Crucify"](http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/toriamos/crucify.html) by Tori Amos from the album [*Little Earthquakes*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Little_Earthquakes), where the following part caught my attention:

> ...
>   I know **a cat named Easter**
>   He says, "Will you ever learn?
>   You're just an empty cage, girl,
>   If you kill the bird."
>   ...

What does the phrase "*I know a cat named Easter*" mean in this context? Is there a subliminal message, say, referring to Cheshire Cat from "Alice in Wonderland" or anything else?

Comment: ELL is for specific questions about English, not for interpretation of poetry or lyrics. That tends to go in the "[bad subjective](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/09/29/good-subjective-bad-subjective/)" direction. If you want to know what it means beyond understanding the slang she's using, you'll have to ask Tori :)

Comment: @ColleenV You are right, this is too subjective, my bad. Could you please re-post your comment as an answer as it actually makes sense to me, and I didn't know about this definition. I wish I could ask Tori, but I remember she wasn't very happy when people were asking about "*pretty hate machine*" in "Caught A Lite Sneeze" and "*Skeeter*" carved in the woods appearing in the "Spark" video. I don't want to disappoint her with my poor English knowledge.

Comment: [Willie And The Hand Jive Lyrics](http://www.metrolyrics.com/willie-and-the-hand-jive-lyrics-eric-clapton.html) start with ***I know a cat named Way-Out Willie***. I'm sure Tori Amos would have been familiar with that at the time.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I agree with ColleenV that this is LitCrit, not language. It's a very complex metaphor which (just to begin with) equates the bird with the singer's soul and the cat with Jesus as at once the bird's predator in the natural order; by His own crucifixion (so different and from the crucifixion the singer finds herself performing on herself), its surrogate; and by His resurrection at Easter its liberator.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Nice observation, thank you! Looks very plausible, as Tori also explicitly mentions [Judy Garland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Judy_Garland) in "Happy Phantom", and probably there are more.

Comment: @StoneyB Thank you for your addition; you are probably right, this phrase is too broad and metaphorically enriched, so please feel free to close the question if it doesn't belong here. As I said, it was still very educational for me.

Comment: While this question is related to the meaning of a phrase in a song, the confusion is primarily over the use of "cat", which many might not understand as slang for "man".  Perhaps the question should be improved, but not closed, as slang is on-topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As ColleenV mentions in her comment, in this song "cat" is probably slang for "guy", as in *"I know a *guy* whose name is 'Easter'"*.

Why he's called "Easter" you'll have to figure out from the context of the song -- assuming there *is* a meaning.  Tori Amos uses a lot of metaphor in her songs, not all of which is significant.

Comment: Or rather, metaphor not all of which is meaningful to anyone other than her. I think a lot of artists have a hard time explaining what a particular collocation means because it isn't really able to be expressed unless you can live inside their brain :)

Comment: @ColleenV  very true. I was immediately reminded of the Sheryl Crow song "Every Day is a Winding Road" which includes the lyrics:  *He's got a daughter he calls Easter / She was born on a Tuesday night / I'm just wondering why I feel so all alone / Why I'm a stranger in my own life*.  The Easter reference makes no sense to me, but I'm sure it's meaningful to Sheryl.